# Two different virtual desktops (different X sessions) on two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two monitors and ATI 34XX graphic card. Ubuntu 12.04.

I'd like to have two different desktops (not virtual workspaces) on these monitors. For example, when I work with left monitor (desktop) it would not affect right one (When I press hot keys, switch virtual workspaces, etc).

I run similar thing on 7.10 or something like that (long time ago), but I can't remember how to do this now.

Another example, I have a Unity WM on left monitor and tile manager Awesome on right one.

I tried to configure this option using AMD control centre, but after reboot I got only I session, another monitor has just a grey background and very odd graphic, looked like no X session on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe going to System Settings > Monitors and tweaking things there does fit what you are looking for? Just a guess, I'm not a expertise in monitors.

Comment: There is no option Monitors in Ubuntu 12.04, only Displays. And no, you can't set such option there.

Comment: I also have been trying to figure out how to get this configuration set up....did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you might be thinking of userful, it used to be in the repos, but isn't anymore the FAQ says it supports at least up until 12.10.

http://www.userful.com/support/all-downloads/uml-download

Here is another page that gives you manual setup options...

http://www.linuxtoys.org/multiubuntu/multiubuntu.html